# How to get page title from URL in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula

If cell A1 contains URL text:

```
http://my.URL.com/some/path/my-page.html
```

How can I write a formula in A2 which extracts the page title:

```
my-page
```

Comment: I'm assuming there's no built in so some sort of regex will be involved, thus the tag. If it can be done without regex, all the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `=REGEXEXTRACT` with a regex featuring the following regex:

```
"^.*/(.*)\.[^.]+$"
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*/` - matches the string up to the last `/`
- `(.*)` - matches *and captures* any 0+ chars up to the last `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]+` - 1 or more chars other than a dot
- `$` - asserts the position at the end of string.

Note that once a capturing group is defined in the pattern, `REGEXEXTRACT` returns the submatch captured.

[image]